# Stop counting score on game over

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i like to have a trigger to stop counting the score when an event happens,

```
function restartStopScore()
     score = score + 0
end
```

will not work

```
score = 0
local scoreText = display.newText( "Score: " .. score, 20, 20,nil, 40)
scoreText:setTextColor(255,255,255)

local function getScore() -- increments Speed value every time it is called
 score = score + 1
 scoreText.text = "Score: " .. score 
 print("score" .. score)
 end
 timer.performWithDelay(1000, getScore, 0)


function restartScore()
     --reset the score
     score = 0   
end
 timer.performWithDelay(5000, restartScore, 1)--test trigger reset the score
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to set a [boolean variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) (*true/false*) for when you want to keep score. Initialize **keeping_score** at the top.

```
keeping_score = true
```

Wrap your score incrementing with this:

```
if keeping_score then
    score = score + 1
end
```

And your start/stop functions will look something like this:

```
function restartStopScore()
    keeping_score = false
end
function restartContinueScore()
    keeping_score = true
end
```